# On OSX what is the opposite command to "say", i.e. what command is there for speech recognition?

Tags: macos, applescript, script, voice-dictation

I'd like to be able to enter a command that registers a speakable word that OS/X can listen for all the time. When the user speaks that word, it should launch an app. Similar to the "OK google" idea.

But is this possible these days? Last I heard of people doing this was in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to System preferences -- Accessibility-- Speakable items
In settings turn on speakable items, and you can provide a keyword. After saying the keyword you can say commands.

Comment: There's no such thing in yosemite.

Comment: Yes, Yosemite does things a little differently, but you can still set up your own voice keywords: http://www.macworld.com/article/2834532/ok-mac-using-automators-dictation-commands-new-in-yosemite.html

Comment: That article appears to be out of date already.